# Delete a column from a tab separated file based on numerical content of column?

Tags: python, bash, perl, csv

I have a tab-separated file, see below:
The first column contains the position number, 1-end
and the rest have some frequency numbers.

```
Position     A    B    C    D
1          117    0    1    0   
2            4    0    0   16   
3            0    5   11    0   
4            0    0    0    5   
5            0   15    0    0   
6          100    0  108    0   
7            0    0  147    0
```

I would like to reformat this file to have two columns, the first is the position column kept as is, and the second contains the highest  frequency for each position.

ideal output:

```
Position    HighFreq
1                117
2                 16  
3                 11  
4                  5   
5                 15   
6                108  
7                147
```

what I have so far is a function that selects the highest number and prints:

```
awk '{max=$1; for(i=2;i<=NF; i++) {if($i>max){max=$i;}};printf"%f\n",max}' file.tsv
```

I'm trying to write a bash solution for this problem, but Perl/Python is most welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{print"Position\tHighFreq"}{if(NR==1)next; max=0;for(i=2;i<=NF; i++) {if($i>max){max=$i;}} printf"%d\t%d\n",$1,max;}' file.tsv
```

output:

```
Position    HighFreq
1   117
2   16
3   11
4   5
5   15
6   108
7   147
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ perl -MList::Util=max -F/\t/ -lane 'print join "\t", $. == 1 ? qw(Position HighFreq) : ( $F [0], max(@F[1..$#F]) )'
```

**Explanation**

- **`-MList::Util=max`**

  Load `List::Util::max`
- **`-F/\t/ -a`**

  Activate auto-split and set delimiter to `/\t/`
- **`-lne`**

  Automatically append appropriate line ending, apply one-liner, process `ARGV` input line-by-line
- **`print join "\t", ...`**

  print tab-separated
- **`$. == 1 ? ... : ...`**

  Handle column headings
- **`max( @F[1..$#F] )`**

  returns max of all-but-first elements of `@F`

Comment: It seems obtuse to confine yourself to the ugliness of a one-liner. Unless you are *certain* that you won't need this functionality again, you will have to go through the coding process again and again in an very unforgiving environment.

Answer (score 0):

As you've chosen a Python tag, this could be done in Python as follows:

```
import sys
import csv

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rb') as f_input:
    tsv = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    next(tsv)
    data = []

    for row in tsv:
        row = map(int, row)
        data.append([row[0]] + [max(row[1:])])

with open(sys.argv[1], 'wb') as f_output:
    tsv = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')
    tsv.writerow(['Position', 'HighFreq'])
    tsv.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';
use autodie;

use List::Util 'max';

open my $fh, '<', 'freq.txt';

<$fh>;
say join "\t", qw/ Position HighFreq /;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    my ($n, @fields) = split;
    say join "\t", $n, max(@fields);
}
```

#### output

```
Position    HighFreq
1   117
2   16
3   11
4   5
5   15
6   108
7   147
```